# Efficient Multiplication of Varying-Length #s [Conceptual]

Tags: math, language-agnostic, recursion, complexity-theory

**EDIT**

So it seems I "underestimated" what varying length numbers meant. I didn't even think about situations where the operands are 100 digits long. In that case, my proposed algorithm is definitely not efficient. I'd probably need an implementation who's complexity depends on the # of digits in each operands as opposed to its numerical value, right?

As suggested below, I will look into the Karatsuba algorithm...

---

*Write the pseudocode of an algorithm that takes in two arbitrary length numbers (provided as strings), and computes the product of these numbers. Use an efficient procedure for multiplication of large numbers of arbitrary length. Analyze the efficiency of your algorithm.*

I decided to take the (semi) easy way out and use the Russian Peasant Algorithm. It works like this:

```
a * b = a/2 * 2b if a is even 
a * b = (a-1)/2 * 2b + a if a is odd
```

My pseudocode is:

```
rpa(x, y){
    if x is 1
        return y
    if x is even
        return rpa(x/2, 2y)
    if x is odd
        return rpa((x-1)/2, 2y) + y
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Is this efficient for arbitrary length numbers? I implemented it in C and tried varying length numbers. The run-time in was near-instant in all cases so it's hard to tell empirically...
2. Can I apply the Master's Theorem to understand the complexity...?

   - a = # subproblems in recursion = 1 (max 1 recursive call across all states)
   - n / b = size of each subproblem = n / 1 -> b = 1 (problem doesn't change size...?)
   - f(n^d) = work done outside recursive calls = 1 -> d = 0 (the addition when a is odd)
   - a = 1, b^d = 1, a = b^d -> **complexity is in n^d*log(n) = log(n)**
   - this makes sense logically since we are halving the problem at each step, right?
3. What might my professor mean by providing arbitrary length numbers "as strings". Why do that?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: He wants to give you numbers as strings because the built-in data types of whatever language you're using are limited to some maximum size.  If he wants you to multiply 198347523458623586235875932485 by 23459876235987623598723645982346598234659823465982346529834, strings are as good a way to represent those numbers as any.  I'm guessing your current algorithm can't handle those inputs...

Comment: Your professor means that the numbers may be too large to fit into a machine word, so they have to be provided as arbitrary-length ASCII strings in (presumably) base 10. For example, "123456789876543211112222333344445". So your algorithm as it stands is woefully incomplete, I'm afraid. But you can use the Russian Peasant Algorithm on strings, too -- you just have to do more work :-/

Comment: Oh, I see. Makes sense -- thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Definitely going to have to rethink this one...

Answer (score 1):

***What might my professor mean by providing arbitrary length numbers "as strings". Why do that?***

This actually change everything about the problem (and make your algorithm incorrect).
It means than 1234 is provided as 1,2,3,4 and you cannot operate directly on the whole number. You need to analyze your algorithm in terms of #additions, #multiplications, #divisions.
You should expect a division to be a bit more expensive than a multiplication, and a multiplication to be lot more expensive than an addition. So a good algorithm try to reduce  the number of divisions and multiplications.

Check out the [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), (ps don't copy it that's not what your teacher want) is one of the fastest for this specification.

Comment: Thank you! I will rethink the problem in terms of which operations to use also and take a look at Karatsuba...

Comment: actually if you can understand karatsuba at the point you can proove its complexity again if requested, you may as well use it.

Comment: great resource for Karatsuba, complete with a recursion tree (how I understand everything ;)): http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/160/notes/31/1.html

Answer (score 0):

Add 3): Native integers are limited in how large (or small) numbers they can represent (32- or 64-bit integers for example). To represent arbitrary length numbers you can choose strings, because then you are not really limited by this. The problem is then, of course, that your arithmetic units are not really made to add strings ;-)